# Neutral prong is hot, but neutral wire is not. Why?

Tags: electrical

I added an outlet in the middle of a circuit, branching from an existing outlet.

I pig-tailed the new outlet two one of the two bundles in the existing outlet and attached the pigtail to the existing outlet's screws.

The second bundle is attached to the second screws. The grounds of all three are attached by pigtail to the single ground screw.

For some reason, the neutral prong reads hot, and the neutral wire does not.

Both downstream outlets seem okay (neutral prongs read neutral, hot prongs read hot).

Should I be concerned? If so, what problems could be causing this?

[image: neutral prong is hot]
[image]

Comment: Sometimes a neutral wire in very close proximity to a line or load wire, *insulation's touching*, will give a false positive with a non contact tester.

Comment: Thanks! So you think maybe the box is crowded, and it's a false positive, and the neutral prong isn't actually hot?

Comment: If you plug something into the outlet, does it work?

Comment: Yes, plugging into the outlet works

Comment: Maybe it's indicating on that L-hook that is only halfway wrapped around the screw :)  Seriously it can't detect that, but it would detect a severed neutral in some cases.   Make that a J-hook and torque it to spec.